# C++ custom conversion between basic types

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Is it possible to provide a custom implicit conversion between the basic types in C++?

Specifically, I have a Xerces-c library that has:

```
using XMLCh = unsigned short int;
```

But of course there is no way to provide a literal string as `unsigned short int`.  So I'd like some like:

```
operator unsigned short int*(char16_t* s) { return reinterpret_cast<unsigned short int*>(s); }
operator char16_t*(unsigned short int* s) { return reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(s); }
```

This would then let you say:

```
XMLCh *str = u"Hello, world.";
```

and:

```
DOMElement* pEl = ...;
std::u16string str = pEl->getNodeName();
```

and so on.  As it stands, I'm going to have to wrap every Xerces call in a conversion function - ugly!

Answer (score 0):

Custom conversion operators can be defined only for `class`es and `struct`s. You can't define them for the built-in types.

Also, custom conversion operators cannot be non-member functions. That limits where they can be defined and what object types they can be defined for.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that.  Can you suggest a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?